# When to use a Scroll View in Android?

Tags: android, scroll, android-widget, scrollview

My question is about best practices in Android in terms of using `ScrollView` to scroll other views and widgets. This is to know when to use a `ScrollView` to eliminate redundancy of scrolling if scrolling is possible in a given widget/view/layouts.

So I notice that there are instances where I don't really need to use `ScrollView` to make things scrollable. Few of the widgets/views/layouts that I know of are `TextView` and `ListView`. This is supported according to [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

> You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView.
>
> The TextView class also takes care of its own scrolling, so does not require a ScrollView, but using the two together is possible to achieve the effect of a text view within a larger container.

My question is, are there other widgets/views/layouts that handles their own scrolling other than the two I have stated above and the documentation has. Maybe there are others that are scrollable or other methods to make things scrollable other than the default of some widgets and by using the `ScrollView`.

Preferred answers must be base on experience and documentation (other than what I've shown). Thanks in advance for any good answers.

Comment: That's kind of a broad question. There are many many views in Android so... I guess you'll end up knowing which views are "self-scrollable" with time and pratice. Also, `ScrollView`s are intended to be used when dealing with lots of views (e.g. many `LinearLayout`s with many views Inside that) and not with just one `View`.

Comment: It might be kind of a broad question and I hope it will help others in the future. Thanks for the addition of when to use scroll views +1 with that.

Answer (score 0):

WebView is one other class that does its own scrolling.  My "best practice" advice is to use ScrollView to add scrolling to an arrangement (usually vertical) of fixed-size widgets.  As you have noted, variable-sized widgets such as ListView provide their own scrolling.

Answer (score -2):

if you read the official documentation you will find that tell you when not to use `ScrollView`:

You should never use a `ScrollView` with a `ListView`, `ListView` Because Takes Care of Its Own Vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing all of the defeats esta Important optimizations in `ListView` for dealing with large lists, since it forces the `ListView` Effectively to displays its Entire list of items to fill up the container supplied by ScrollView infinite.

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: This is the same link I have on my question, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: I think is the better definition to know when use scrollview, i hope this help you ;)